# Sonarqube ignoring angular unit test spec files

Tags: angular, testing, sonarqube, karma-jasmine

We have a Quality Gates for our Angular 13 project, and we have to make our coverage more than 80%.

The problem is the SonarQube which lives on our dev server is ignoring the unit test files, it shows 'Coverage –'.
[image: image of it]

Is there a problem on our server and we need some changes in a config file maybe to work it, or it is a problem with our Angular project?

`npm test` is generating the coverage folder, but the coverage folder is in our `.gitignore`. `"test": "ng test --code-coverage"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it.
In the Angular project just set in the `karma.conf.js`

```
  coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      reports: ['lcovonly'],
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [{ type: 'lcov' }],
    },
```

run `ng test --code-coverage`
We are using docker, so sonar cli docker have to run this:
`-Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info`